# how to programmatically deselect a static cell iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a static cell and when clicked it launches a modal view. Except when i return from the modal view the cell is still selected? Why is it doing this and how can I make it only make the cell selected until the modal completely covers the view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndex, [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController` this will be done automatically. Otherwise, you need to do the deselecting yourself using 
[deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:) on the `UITableView`. The best place to do this is probably on `viewDidAppear:` of the presenting view controller. That way, the user still sees the deselecting animation allowing them to reorient themselves.

If you don't need to track the selected row for other purposes, you can use 
[indexPathForSelectedRow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) to determine which index path needs to be deselected (if any).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :) Ok firstly I am using a UITableViewController so I'm not sure why its not automatically doing it.

Comment: @Tomblasta Make sure that clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is set to true and that the tableView is properly assigned as the UITableViewController's tableview.

Comment: Sorry, this is a noob question, but where would I declare the clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear method?

Comment: @Tomblasta that's not a method, that's a property on UITableViewController. A good place to set it is in either an initializer or in viewDidLoad. (Note that in those cases you will be setting it on self: 'self.clearsSelectiomOnViewWillAppear = true')

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 2 :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

For Swift 3 and 4 :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
         tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: i got an error from this but if you add this code it works perfectly 
if tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil {
your code
} 
that's because first time nothing will be selected

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late but may help someone who's using Swift -

**This will give a nice effect when you return to masterViewController from detailViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
  {
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  }
}
```

**Otherwise add this delegate method of TableView and call it from didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your **UITableViewController**;

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

In your condition, ***yourTableView*** property should be ***self.tableView***

Comment: Thanks, how would i get the index path of a static cell? @KemalCanKaynak

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
}
```